# wsl --set-default-version 2 The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it

Tags: failed-installation, wsl-2

I'm trying to install again Ubuntu on my Windows 10 Home Version 20H2 OS Build 19042.685 using WSL2.

The problem is the WSL2 installation is not finished.
I received the following message doing Step 5 - Set WSL 2 as your default version

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
```

Previous steps done:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.572

Image Version: 10.0.19042.685

Enabling feature(s)
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.572

Image Version: 10.0.19042.685

Enabling feature(s)
[==========================100.0%==========================]
The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Then I restarted Windows and

```
execute wsl_update_x64.msi
```

Comment: Your title says that you receive the error when executing `wsl --set-default-version 2`, but the output you copied says that you just typed `wsl`.  That would simply attempt to launch your default WSL instance, but you haven't installed one yet (that's step 6).  Can you confirm that you are receiving the error when *also* typing `wsl --set-default-version 2` and not just `wsl`?

Comment: Also, this would be better suited to [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).  Stack Overflow questions should be *programming* based.

Comment: I issues the 2 commands wsl --set-default-version 2 and wsl. They give me the same answer.PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --set-default-version 2
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

Answer (score 69):

I had the same issue:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --set-default-version 2
The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
```

The problem was Kaspersky. The solution is simple: open `cmd.exe` **as administrator** and run the following code

```
sc config LxssManager start=auto
```

Kaspersky will give you a pop-up about a potential thread. Tell Kaspersky to ignore the alert. Please don't click on "Fix it" button for Kaspersky or you will undo the solution.

That should fix it.

Comment: Yes, Kaspersky was blocking it the whole time, therefore affecting Docker.

Comment: Note: Use CMD, not powershell (`sc` is a apparently a command only for CMD), and open it as admin.

Comment: I returns error `Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'start=auto'.` even in the admin mode.

Answer (score 8):

Docans is right; running:

`sc config LxssManager start=auto`

in Command Prompt seems to fix the issue. However, you must run Command Prompt as an Administrator. I don't have enough reputation to comment or edit the post to clarify this so I have to make it a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

PS: Windows Command shell needs to be open with Admin privileges (Run as administrator)

Comment: P.S. of what? You didn't write anything before